# What are the Game Boy Advance (GBA) Game Pak ROM cartridge physical dimensions (length x width x height)?

Tags: game-boy-advance

Per Title, preference for official Nintendo technical specifications, if available, for the GBA Class D/Advance Game Pak cartridges. In mm/cm, preferably.

If no official Nintendo technical specifications, might someone please provide accurately measured dimensions?

Note: this refers to the dimensions of the plastic cartridge housing, not any internal components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not been able to find any sources (official or otherwise) that list measurements of the cartridges. So I dug my GBA out of storage, dusted it off and took a measuring tape to a cartrige. The cartridges are approximately 57mm x 8mm x 35mm. My measurements may be off by about 0.5mm.

I compiled more detailed measurements into a graphic:

[image: Blank cartridge image courtesy of Nerdysimmer https://vgboxart.com/resource/515/gameboy-advance-template/]

The notches and beveled edges are on both sides, and the finger grip at the top juts out 2-2.5mm from the width of the cartridge to aide in pulling it out of the system.